# Woman arrives 6s late for the train. Find her velocity to reach it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A woman arrives exactly 6 seconds after a train leave the station at a constant acceleration of $0.4m/s^2$. Find the minimum constant velocity she might run to get in the train.

What I did:

I wrote an equation for the distance of the train up to 6 seconds. Since its velocity grows linearly, after $6$ seconds we would have $V_t = 0.4*6 = 2.4m/s$. So after $6$ seconds, its position is:

$$S = 0 + 2.4*6 + \frac{1}{2}0.4*6^2 = 7.2m$$

Then we can write a new equation for the train, that takes time $t=0$ when the woman arrives at the station:

$$S_t = 7.2 + 2.4*t + \frac{1}{2}0.4*t^2$$

Also, the equation for the woman's position is

$$S_w = 0 + v*t$$

We should have $S_t = S_w$ but I would end up with $2$ variables.

What can I do to finish this exercise?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: Sketch it on a (x,t) PLOT, try using different velocities v. Notice that drawing a tangent will be the best possible solution, Once you understand how to do that. you can convert it into an algebraic problem.

Comment: equation 1 is wrong $d = \int at dt = at^2/2$ that is all. No extra terms That is ofcourse assuming train starts are zero velocity. Who is teaching you this subject. You seem to be making elementary mistakes.

Comment: The relavant quadratic equation is $d_t-d_w = at^2/2-v_m(t-6) = 0$ This quadratic has one solution when $v_m^2 = 4*a*6*v_m/2$ giving $v_m = 4.8m/s$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thoughts on this problem:

There are two variables, yes: $t$ and $v_{woman}$. Solve for t! You get 0, 1 or 2 solutions, depending on $v_{woman}$. The problem says, however, that you want the minimum $v_{woman}$ velocity. If you get 0 solutions, for t, it means that they'll never meet. If you get two, then the woman gets in front of the train, which after a while gains more velocity than hers and gets in front of her again. Thus the case you are looking for is when there is only one meeting point, one t solution for which $d(t) = 7.2 -v_{woman} \cdot t + 2.4 \cdot t + \frac{0.4}{2} \cdot t^2 = 0 $. I got $v_{woman} = 4.8 \frac{m}{s}$.